# Facebook sharing popup asking for confirmation

Tags: facebook, sharing, confirmation

Anyone knows the reason why facebook share dialog can ask for confirmation? It started to happen after moving from one domain to another (.com to .eu), but I'm not sure.

After clicking on send inside sharing popup I receive response from https://m.facebook.com/plugins/confirm/share/sentry with

```
{"payload":{"actions":[{"cmd":"replace","target":"confirm-button","html":"..."}]}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Wm5.png)

Comment: Because the system think it may be spam. When enough people have shared it will go away.